# (How) can I emulate {eshell,comint}-output-filter-functions in term?

Tags: hooks, eshell, term, comint

What I want to do from inside a term shell is have a function called when there is new output or a certain regexp (e.g. a prompt) appears in in a term's output. The callback function should then be able to access text from the either the last time it was called, or from the last time that pattern was seen.

In `comint` this would be a function stored in 
`comint-output-filter-functions`, and for `eshell`: `eshell-output-filter-functions`

Can this be done in term.el? If so, how?

Comment: You could add a `:before` advice to `term-emulate-terminal` -- the `process-filter` of the `buffer-process` of a `term` buffer.

Comment: I don't understand. And I'm not good at inference. I can try experimenting but I need more details. Perhaps code snippets and/or links to concepts you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concrete example using the old style advice:

```
(defadvice term-emulate-terminal (before out-terminal-string activate)
  (message "%s" str))
```

Notes:

- `term-emulate-terminal` is the output process filter for terminals
- `output-terminal-string` is a label for this advice, change as you please
- The variable `str` matches the string variable used in `term-emulate-terminal`. In this advice style you are allowed to directly reference the original arguments by name.

Comment: Seems interesting although I don't have time right now to check it out. I will later. Thanks.

Comment: Take your time. I spent a reasonable amount of time messing with this recently, so if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask. My purpose was to get pdbtrack working with term/ansi-term, which I was successful with.

Comment: Want to get realgud working with term/ansi-term? I'd be eternally grateful. https://github.com/realgud/realgud/blob/master/realgud/common/track-mode.el#L143-L149

Comment: I'll even add a bounty for it if you do it - name your price :-)

Comment: I don't use realgud at the moment, partially because I often don't have access to more than vanilla emacs 24+. However, looking at your comint hook, it looks like you take the approach that pdbtrack takes with its comint hook, you track the actual comint buffer rather than the text string passed to the hook function. When getting pdbtrack working with term/ansi-term I use the actual text passed to my hook/advice. This was enough in my case, but there is a note in your hook comments about "piecing the text together", could you elaborate? JohnLunzer@github.

Comment: Let me explain "piecing the text together": when there is a lot of output, or the produced output takes time, there isn't one callback, but several. In a debugger for example you might issue a "backtrace" command to list the cal lstack. That typically may have lots of output, and may take a while to create, so there output may be in two parts. As for realgud and emacs 24, I had thought it worked on 24.3. If you want to suggest changes where it faulty by all means do put in a pull request.

Comment: I look at your github account but I don't see which project modifies pdbtrack. Where is this code?

Comment: Ahh, forgive my newbishness, you won't find anything there yet, I haven't checked in the code. I always forget that github does not all PMs, my intent was to take the conversation "offline". Now I better understand the predicament of having to piece together output, my own solution to getting pdbtrack working in term is really only a partial solution due to my simplified approach. I took a shot today at tailing the term output, as a means of grabbing the complete output but it wasn't too successful. I'm going to try again, if I'm successful I'll let you know and share the code.

Comment: Btw, realgud probably does work in 24.3. I'm just trying to stay closer to a vanilla configuration and since I only require pdbtrack working inside term I don't really need all of realgud, just a few functions and advice in my emacs config.